# A set contains $0$, $1$, and all averages of any subset of its element, prove it contains all rational number between 0 and 1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Assume we have a set $S$ $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we know $0,1 \in S$. Also, $S$ has the property that if $A \subseteq S$ is finite, the average of elements in $A$ is in $S$. We want to prove that any rational number between 0 and 1 is contained in $S$.

Can someone please give me a hint?  I tried to use induction but it seems hopeless to me...

Comment: What do you mean by $2^S$?

Comment: @AitorOrmazabal Power set, presumably

Comment: @AitorOrmazabal yes it means power set

Comment: what else did you try after you realized that induction was hopeless? What numbers are guaranteed to be in your set? what can you do with them?

Comment: Could you consider a fraction and then work backwards to see how one could generate that value as an average? For example, $\frac{1}{2}$ is in S since {0,1} would have that as an average. Just an idea.

Comment: Trying to show first that every fraction of the form $\dfrac {p}{2^n}$ is in $S$ might be helpful

Comment: @uniquesolution I can show elements of form $1/2^i$ is in $S$, also their average with 1, and their sums is in S.. but I didn't see more

Comment: @JBKing but I cannot even find how to form 1/3...

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that $S$ can actually only be assumed to contain every fraction whose denominator is a power of two in irreducible form.

Comment: Could you make a set like {0,0,1} which would have an average of $\frac{1}{3}$? That would be one idea. The other would be to consider what does that fraction look like in base 2 and see if you could put together the fractional elements as it would be a repeating decimal. http://www.ms.uky.edu/~rbrown/courses/ma321.f.04/lec03.pdf has the conversion if you need it though I'm not totally sure about this one.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong I thought you were only allowed to take the average of two elements, if you can do what JB said then it seems possible

Comment: Note that $\{0,0,1\}$ is usually considered to contain only two elements. You can form $1/3$ reasonably easily. Aitor is at least right that you can't do it with only two-element sets. So play around with three-element sets and see what happens.

Comment: @BenMillwood I don't think we can form 1/3 by using average on {0,0,1}, first of all it is not a set.. if somehow we can show that every weighted average of 0 and 1 is in $S$ then it is solved..

Comment: $\{0,0,1\}$ is a set, but it is equal to $\{0,1\}$ and has average $1/2$, so you're correct that you can't make $1/3$ with that set. So... follow the rest of my advice?

Comment: Note that the average of three elements will be the sum of some three numbers divided by $3$, so that gives you a hint about what to look for

Comment: @AitorOrmazabal isn't that just the equation for average number? some more hints please?..

Comment: It's annoying that you can't do {0,0,1} to average 1/3, but you can do {1/4, 3/4, 0} => 1/3.  It'll take a bit of finessing but I think you can get all 1/n in a similar manner.

Comment: Could this be as simple as saying "because all rational numbers between 0 and 1 can be represented in binary"?

Comment: @corsiKa no because that representation may not end in finite digits. 0.1 is an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily get all dyadic rationals (rationals expressible with denominator as a power of $2$).  In fact these dyadic rationals can always be taken as the average of two other elements in the set.  For instance you have $0, 1$. From these two wholes you can get the halfs (just $\frac12$ is new) from the halfs you can get the fourths.  From the fourths you can get the eighths. Etc.

I proceed by example, because I'm not sure how to write an exact proof, but I think the ideas are here.

For instance let's try to get some fractions with denominator $5$ as averages of (dyadic) fractions with denominator $8$.  We have available $\frac08,\frac18,\frac28,\frac38,\frac48,\frac58,\frac68,\frac78,\frac88$.

If we take a sum of five of these with numerators adding to a multiple of $8$, we will get an average with a denominator of $5$.
So for instance $\frac08,\frac18,\frac28,\frac58\frac88$ gives an average of $\frac25$.  Or $\frac28,\frac38,\frac48,\frac78,\frac88$ gives an average of $\frac35$.  You can't get $\frac45$ using eighths.  But you can with sixteenths.

These ideas should generalize, but as I say I am unsure how to write a formal proof.  So feel free to improve upon this answer!

Answer (score 8):

Assume there is some $\frac ab\notin A$ (with $0\le a\le b$) and among all such counterexamples consider one with minimal denominator $b$ (especially, $\frac ab$ is in shortest termes).
Then certainly $b>1$.
If $b$ is a power of $2$, note that $a$ is odd and $\frac ab=\frac12\left(\frac{(a-1)/2}{b/2}+\frac{(a+1)/2}{b/2}\right)\in A$, contradiction. 
Thus let $p$ be an odd prime dividing $b$, $b=pc$.
Then by minimality of $b$, all fractions $\in[0,1]$ with denominator dividing $c$ are $\in A$. Also all fractions with denominator dividing $2^kc$ for some $k\in \Bbb N_0$ are $\in A$ (by induction as above: $\frac xy$ with $x$ odd is the average of $\frac{(x-1)/2}{y/2}$ and $\frac{(x+1)/2}{y/2}$).
Let $\hat c=2^kc$ and $\hat b=p\hat c=2^kb$ where $k$ is chosen large enough so that 
$$\tag1 \hat c>6p-12$$
or, as a consequence of $(1)$
$$\tag2 \hat b+2\ge 3{p-1\choose 2}. $$
For $0\le x\le b$
we might try to write $\frac x{\hat b}$ as average of $p$ fractions with denominator (a divisor of) $\hat c$. For this we should find $p$ numbers $x_i$, $i=1,\ldots,p$, with $0\le x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_p\le c$ and $x_1+\ldots+x_p=x$.
This would give us $\frac xb=\frac1p\left(\frac{x_1}c+\ldots+\frac{x_p}c\right)\in A$ as desired.
However, the smallest possible pick for $x_1+\ldots +x_p$ is $0+1+2+\ldots +(p-1)={p-1\choose 2}$ and the largest is $p\hat c-{p-1\choose 2}$ (and all this is possible in the first place because $(1)$ guarantees $\hat c\ge p-1$); but at least we can obtain all intermediate integers as sum, as we can always "step up" by increasing $x_p$ if it is $< c$ or any of the other $x_i$ that is $<x_{i+1}-1$!
We thus conclude that $\frac x{\hat b}\in A$ for  ${p-1\choose 2}\le x\le b-{p-1\choose 2}$. 
Assume there exists $x$ with $0<x<{p-1\choose 2}$ with $\frac x{\hat b}\notin A$. 
Let $x_0$ be the maximal such $x$. Then $\frac{2x_0}{\hat b}\notin A$ as otherwise we would have $\frac{x_0}{\hat b}\in A$ as average of $0$ and $\frac{2x_0}{\hat b}$. But then the maximality of $x_0$ implies $2x_0\ge {p-1\choose 2}$ and that makes $2x_0\le 2\left({p-1\choose 2}-1\right)\le \hat b-{p-1\choose 2}$ by $(2)$ and so $\frac{2x_0}{\hat b}\in A$ again, contradiction. The same argument works with numerators $>\hat b-{p-1\choose 2}$ by averaging against $1$.
We conclude $\frac x{\hat b}\in A$ for all $x$, $0\le x\le \hat b$.
In particular, $\frac ab=\frac{2^ka}{\hat b}\in A$, contradiction.

Comment: Novel approach! +1. This is a problem from A Mathematical Orchard by MAA, and while I recall something of how the solution was, it certainly was not done this way...

Answer (score 1):

Consider these possibilities:

{0,$\frac{1}{a}$,$\frac{1}{b}$} would average $\frac{a+b}{3ab}$

{1,$\frac{1}{a}$,$\frac{1}{b}$} would average $\frac{ab+a+b}{3ab}$

{$\frac{1}{a}$,$\frac{1}{b}$,$\frac{1}{c}$} would average $\frac{bc+ac+ab}{3abc}$

Consider using, a,b and c as powers of 2 and see what new values you can add.

{0,.5, .125} for a half and an eighth that would give a 24th: $\frac{5}{24}$, (4+1=5)

{1,.5, .125} would give a different 24th for an average here: $\frac{13}{24}$, (8+4+1=13)

Now take the average of {$\frac{13}{24}$,$\frac{1}{8}$} and you'll get $\frac{13+3}{24*2}=\frac{16}{48}= \frac{1}{3}$

---

Would there exist a similar construct using fractions of an 16th to make a 1 using 5 elements?

6+4+3+2+1=16 where 3/8ths, 1/4th, 3/16ths, 1/8th and 1/16th could be used to derive 1/5th? Granted this is using higher powers of 2 for each number but if there exists a partition of $2^n$ using q or (q-1) parts then it isn't that hard to generate it out.

Averaging with 0 or 1 can produce a few other values as after 1/5 is generated, averaging 1 with it would produce 3/5ths that may generalize.

Comment: Or just use $0, \frac14, \frac34$ to get $\frac13$

Comment: This shows that there are some positive numbers in $S$ of the form $p/q$ in lowest terms where $q$ is not a power of $2$, contradicting some of the comments. However, if all rationals are in $S$, then your proposed outline using averages of 3 terms doesn't show how to get $1/q$ when $q \neq 2,3$. And even if you do have $1/q \in S$, it also needs proof that this implies $p/q \in S$ for all $p$ between 2 and $q-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more explicit construction than given in other answers.

As other answers, first notice that it’s quite easy to get all dyadic numbers in $[0,1]$, i.e. numbers of the form $\frac{n}{2^a}$, where $0 \leq n \leq 2^a$.

Now suppose you want to get $\frac{p}{q}$.  If you can find $q$ distinct dyadic numbers $x_1$, …, $x_q$ whose sum is exactly $p$, then the average of these will be $\frac{p}{q}$.  How can you find those distinct dyadic numbers with the right sum?  There are lots of ways to do this, but here’s one.  Since the dyadic numbers are *dense*, you can take them to be close approximations of $\frac{p}{q}$ itself.  First pick a denominator $2^a$ to use (for all the $x_i$).  Now, using this denominator, take all but one of the numbers $x_i$ to be below $\frac{p}{q}$, but as close as possible to it; and then pick the last number,$x_q$, to be whatever is needed to balance out the total shortfall of the rest, to make the total sum $p$.

We’re nearly done, but not quite.  Let’s look at what this method gives for making 1/3.  We’re looking for three dyadics with sum 1.  With denominator 4, we get 0, 1/4 as the nearest ones below 1/3, and then 3/4 to bring the total up to 1.  With denominator 8, we get 1/8, 2/8 as the ones below 3, and then 5/8 as the last number.  With denominator 16, we get 4/16, 5/16, and 7/16.

What about for 1/5?  We want five dyadics summing to 1, starting with four below 1/5.  Trying denominator 4, the four closest aproximations by quarters below 1/5 are… 0, –1/4, –2/4, and –3/4.  Oops.  By eighths, not much better.  By sixteenths, we have 3/16, 2/16, 1/16, and 0/16; and then 10/16 is just right to bring the sum up to 1.  Success!

What about for 2/3?  We want three dyadics with sum 2.  Trying quarters, we get 2/4 and 1/4 as the approximations below it… but then we would need 5/4 to bring the sum up to 2.  Trying with eighths, we get 5/8 and 4/8 as the approximations-below; and 7/8 to finish.  Success!

Generally, for $\frac{p}{q}$: trying this method, with denominator $2^a$, we get approximations-below of $k/2^a$, $(k-1)/2^a$, …, $(k–q+2)/2^a$, where $k = \lfloor{2^a p / q}\rfloor$, i.e. the largest numerator such that $k/2^a \leq p/q$.  Then the last number we pick must bring the sum of the numerators up to $2^a p$, so must be $(2^a p – \sum_{i=0}^{q-2}(k-i))/2^a$.

This will always give a set of $q$ distinct dyadic numbers with average $p/q$.  As the examples above show, sometimes some of these dyadics will be outside $[0,1]$.  But if you take $a$ large enough (how large? I’ll leave that as an exercise…) then these numbers will be in $[0,1]$, and so you’re done.

Answer (score 0):

We can explicitly construct sets to average more easily if we don't restrict ourselves to dyadics.

Define the set $T$ to be all positive integers $n$ such that $0 \leq p \leq n \implies \frac{p}{n} \in S$.

In order to prove the result, we want to show that all positive integers are in $T$.

Given any $n \in T$, we can prove that

- $\frac{p}{2n} \in S$ for $0 < p \leq n$ by averaging {0, $\frac{p}{n}$}
- $\frac{p}{2n} \in S$ for $n \leq p < 2n$ by averaging {1, $\frac{p-n}{n}$}

Since $\frac{0}{2n}$ and $\frac{2n}{2n}$ are both in S by the original definition, $2n \in T$.

By induction, it is now obvious that $n \in T \implies 2^jn \in T$ for any positive integer $j$.

Given $n \in T$, we can now show that $\frac{p}{2n+1} \in S$ for $0 < p \leq n$ by choosing $j$ such that $2^j > 2n$ and averaging this set:

{0, $\frac{p}{2^jn}$, $\frac{(2^j-1)p}{2^jn}$, 
$\frac{2p}{2^jn}$, $\frac{(2^j-2)p}{2^jn}$, ... , 
$\frac{np}{2^jn}$, $\frac{(2^j-n)p}{2^jn}$}

Each pair of non-zero elements adds to $p/n$ and there are $n$ pairs; including the zero the average is therefore $\frac{p}{2n+1}$ as desired.  The requirement that $2^j > 2n$ ensures that no two elements are equal and also that they are all within $[0,1]$ and hence (since $2^jn \in T$) are elements of $S$.

To show that $\frac{p}{2n+1} \in S$ for $n < p < 2n + 1$ we can define $r=(2n+1)-p$ and use the set

{1, 1 - $\frac{r}{2^jn}$, 1 - $\frac{(2^j-1)r}{2^jn}$, 
1 - $\frac{2r}{2^jn}$, 1 - $\frac{(2^j-2)r}{2^jn}$, ... , 
1 - $\frac{nr}{2^jn}$, 1 - $\frac{(2^j-n)r}{2^jn}$}

Each pair in this set adds to $2 - \frac{r}{n}$ so the $n$ pairs add to $2n - r$ and the set to $2n + 1 - r$ which is equal to $p$, so the average is again $\frac{p}{2n+1}$ and it is easy to show that the elements do not repeat and are all within $[0,1]$.

Since we have shown $0 < p < 2n + 1 \implies \frac{p}{2n+1} \in S$, and since $\frac{0}{2n+1}$ and $\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}$ are both in S by the original definition, we have shown that $2n+1 \in T$.

---

Having shown that $n \in T$ implies both $2n \in T$ and $2n+1 \in T$, and since $1 \in T$ by the definition of $S$, it is trivial to show by induction that all positive integers $n$ are in $T$.  QED.